# setInterval doesn't get cleared, function keeps getting executed

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, raspberry-pi

I have the following function:

```
function monitorClimate() {

    var sensorReadingInterval;

    function startClimateMonitoring(interval) {

        sensorReadingInterval = setInterval(function() {

            io.emit('sensorReading', {
                temperature: sensor.getTemp() + 'C',
                humidity: sensor.getHumidity() + '%'
            });

        }, interval);

        console.log('Climate control started!');

    }

    function stopClimateMonitoring() {
        clearInterval(sensorReadingInterval);
        console.log('Climate control stopped!');
    }


    return {
        start: startClimateMonitoring,
        stop: stopClimateMonitoring
    };

}
```

I am watching a button for changes of state like this:

```
button.watch(function(err, value) {
    led.writeSync(value);

    if (value == 1) {
        monitorClimate().start(1000);
    } else {
        monitorClimate().stop();
    }

});
```

The problem is that even after the `monitorClimate().stop()` call, setInterval keeps getting triggered, thus SocketIO keeps on emitting the sensorReading event.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's the point of your closure if you recreate a scope by calling the function each time you use your API? Your different calls simply aren't executed in the same place. It's different functions, so different intervals.

Comment: you need an executor service definitely, the code is messy.

Comment: Thank you guys! I'm clearly a newbie, so finding the best pattern is often times a challenge to me. @RomanC can you point me to some reading materials on the Executor Service? Or maybe some source code implementing it... Simple google search led me to an NPM package. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: @MartinVelchevski No, definitely it shouldn't be used by a newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you call `monitorClimate()` you are creating a new set of functions so `monitorClimate().start()` and `monitorClimate().stop()` are not working on the same interval. Try something like:

```
var monitor = monitorClimate();
button.watch(function(err, value) {
    led.writeSync(value);

    if (value == 1) {
        monitor.start(1000);
    } else {
        monitor.stop();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much @wezzy! I moved the  `sensorReadingInterval` to the 'global' scope, this along with your addition (grabbing an instance of the function) made it work. I'll try and think of a better pattern for this. Judging by the comments on the question, this might not be the right approach.

Comment: This answer doesn't fix anything.  You're still calling `monitorClimate` each time the button is pushed and creating new `start`/`stop` functions.  The change to `sensorReadingInterval` being global solved the issue on its own.

Comment: @AaronDufour I realise that. I marked the answer as 'accepted' because it pointed me in the right direction. There was another answer by a different user but it got deleted for some reason.

Comment: The value in marking answers accepted is for future readers.  It is going to be misleading for anyone who looks at this question in the future, because the suggested fix is quite clearly a no-op change.  I would suggest writing an answer of your own with the actual answer and accepting that instead.